# Sistema de "Upgrades" en js

Tags: javascript, html, css, funciones, variables

primero que todo todo este código esta modificado de un video de YouTube en el que me base y por el que cree este código y otros mas que lo acompañan en HTML, css. Mi pregunta/o problema es que a la de hora de hacer que la función de mejoras funcione no lo hace la imagen no aparece y no hay ningún error en consola que será?

```
var upgrades = {
nameUpgr: [
    "Evil Ducks"
],
descriptionUpgr: [
    "Now ducks are 100% more efficient"
],
imageUpgr: [
    "idk/duckupgrade.jpg"
],
type: [
    "building"
],
costUpgr: [
    50
],
buildingIndex: [
    0
],
requierements: [
    5
],
bonus: [
    2
],
purchased: [
    false
],
purchaseUpgr: function(index) {
    if (!this.purchased[index] && game.score >= this.costUpgr[index]) {
        if (this.type[index] == "building" && building.count[this.buildingIndex[index]] >= this.requierements[index]) {
            game.score -= this.costUpgr[index];
            building.incoms[this.buildingIndex[index]] *= this.bonus[index];
            this.purchased[index] = true;

            display.updateScore();
            display.updateUpgrades();
        } else if (this.type[index] == "click" && game.totalClicks >= this.requierements[index]) {
            game.score -= this.costUpgr[index];
            game.clickValue *= this.bonus[index];
            this.purchased[index] = true;

            display.updateScore();
            display.updateUpgrades();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Aquí esta todo mi código en js, para que lo puedas revisar y ayudar a saber cual es el problema aquí. https://pastebin.com/f816Y8Sr

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en ESPAÑOL, por favor lee [ask] , te darás cuenta que las preguntas deben estar en ESPAÑOL.